# IMAP Libraries for iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, open-source, imap

I have been trying to build the framework MailCore which is a dependency in a open source project, that is ReMail. I have followed all the steps given on ReMail Website (http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/) to get that project from their repo, but the code is still not getting built. Is there any other good alternative to MailCore for talking a IMAP server and pulling the mails from it?

Thanks,
Ulhas

Comment: I have Working reMail. You need to download all the libraries through shell script given into reMail. Read reMail Project's included readme files carefully. It's about 1.5 gb of data to download.

Comment: i have pulled all the dependencies using the command sh pull_dependencies.sh . but i am still unable to build it. the files are getting downloaded but is giving error due to linking errors. 

also, which commit have u pulled for mailcore?

Comment: The last one because it is not updated since a long time.

Comment: i cloned the repo on tuesday. so presumably the latest commit would be pulled, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MailCore is basically a wrapper around [libetpan](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libetpan/). A wrapper around a very old version of libetpan.

There is a new libetpan version available that I use successfully in an app.

Comment: it would be nice of you to give the link of the new libetpan library.

Comment: same location where the old (= 0.4.5) is. http://sourceforge.net/projects/libetpan/files/libetpan/1.0/